# What means "with the DJIA at 892"?

Tags: stocks, investing, stock-markets

The question says it all: What means "with the DJIA at 892"? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably it means that the value of the Dow Jones Industrial Average at that time was 892. The value was around that number for much of the 1960s, 1970s, and early 1980s.

Comment: Hi! But, what type of value? Thanks.

Comment: @PedroRelvas I don't know what you mean. The Dow Jones Industrial Average is just a number that changes over time. At one point in time, that number was 892. Are you asking what the meaning of the number is?

Comment: It's essentially just a (weighted) sum of the share prices of the stock that makes up the index.

Comment: @TannerSwett Yes. Thank you.

Comment: The dow jones isn't weighted. It's just the sum of the 30 stocks it contains